# How to make my app interact with Android home screen?

Tags: popup, widget, homescreen, accessibilityservice, home-screen-widget

I am building an app that uses frontal camera to track where user is looking at the screen. When user blinks, smartphone registers that as a tap. Currently it works "inside" my app. I have a few dots around the screen, when i look at one of them and blink, it changes color.

But how can I make it work on the home screen/with other apps? Say if user looked at the facebook app, blinked, it would open.

I was thinking of a pop up window like Skype. I could design it as a cursor and it would be displayed above the home screen and all apps. But if i would blink(tap) it would perform an action inside that popup/widget and not click "through" it.

Are there any codes that can make my app interact with other apps. Maybe Accessibility services?

There is a similar app that can create a mouse on the homescreen, when user waves his hand (no physical touch) it registers that as a tap. How can I recreate that?

Picture attached...

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UeOW.png)

Comment: Maybe a transparent window over the home screen, or write your own "home screen" *AKA* a launcher app. **OR** [completely-control-your-android-device-with-just-your-head](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/completely-control-your-android-device-with-just-your-head-0175737/)

Comment: That does look similar to what i am trying to do. It says that once user hovers his head pop up appears with a "click" option. When user clicks, cursor taps on whatever it is pointing at. Any idea how to recreate it code wise? Thank you!

Comment: Please take the time to take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) ,(particularly related to how to ask a *good* question on the site) *we're a little bit different from other sites*, **AND** you get a badge for it !

Comment: [eva_facial_mouse source code](https://github.com/cmauri/eva_facial_mouse) is in the GitHub, free for you to copy/change as you like, as far as I can see.